# Python 3: Alignment and commas

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my Concepts of Programming course in college, we need to use functions in Python 3 to create a data table that involves numbers in the thousands. We need to include commas in the numbers. I would like to use spacing in the format. Is there a way to keep spacing to keep the table aligned and still be able to use commas in the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
n = 1303344095
"{:15,d}".format(n)
```

Yields:

```
'  1,303,344,095'
```

So you can provide a field width specification, and then the comma specification, then the type specification, within the overall format spec. It also works with floating point numbers, albeit with an uglier syntax:

```
f = 1299.21
"{:10,.2f}".format(f)
```

Yields:

```
'  1,299.21'
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! I'm new to this, and the school year just started. We're pretty much teaching ourselves for formatting and the like.